# Add row before tr not working

Tags: jquery, html

My question is related to my existing question. Please refer my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MJGV2/2/)

If I click the "add row" button tr will be added. I want to add tr before the "add row" button.

I tried following code:

```
 $tr.prependTo($(this).closest('tr'));
```

to

```
 $tr.insertBefore($(this).closest('tr'));
```

But no use. I couldn't fix it. Anyone can save my hour??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) as [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live) is removed from newer **jQuery versions**. Also use `counter class` as `id` must be unique

```
$(".AddRow").on('click',function () {
    var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);
        var $input = $tr.find('input.startdatum');
        var index = $tr.find('input.counter').val();
        $tr.find('.AddRow').val('Delete') // set value to Delete
           .toggleClass('AddRow delete') // toggle classes
           .unbind('click'); // unbind the current events from button
        var id = 'datepicker' + index;
        index++;
        $tr.find('input.counter').val(index);
        $input.attr('id', id).data('index', index);
        $tr.prependTo($(this).closest('table'));
        setdatepicker();
});
// bind click event to delete entire row
$(document).on('click','.delete',function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/MJGV2/30/)**

Also if you see your code then it is `prepending` the row rather than `appending`, if you apply your `index` as `new tr class` then you can see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

i changed this line, and its working...

```
 var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').clone().insertBefore(this);

 $tr.prependTo($(this).closest('table'));
```

Comment: I tried this code. The add button is hide. I want to display this button also.